# What are Epilog x-Axis Positions In BoxWhiskerChart (with BarSpacing option)?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, charts

I have a dataset that has a number of groups with overlapping sets. There is a point in the group within the intersection of the sets that I want to highlight by placing a marker of that point between the sets in the group.

I want to do use `BoxWhiskerChart` to show the distribution of the groups and place the marker between the plots in the group.  The problem is that I have not been able to figure out where the box plots will be centered in the chart.  Or better the x-axis range that each box plot occupies.  This is further complicated by the fact that the locations change significantly as the `BarSpacing` option changes.

Is there a way to get the x-axis range that each box plot occupies in a `BoxWhiskerChart` (or at least the centre of each box plot) as the `BarSpacing` option varies?

This is a reasonable example of the problem I am trying to solve. Notice how the highlighted points do not line appear between the group box plots and jump around as `BarSpacing` is changed. I'd really like to use the `Method -> {"BoxWidth" -> "Scaled"}` option but I can't even get the fixed width option to work yet.

```
(*group dataset*)
data = Table[RandomVariate[
  NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1.5], 100],{3}, {2}];
(*get intersections and point within intersection for example*)
minsAndMaxes = Map[{Min[#], Max[#]} &, data, {2}];
groupIntersections = 
  Map[IntervalIntersection[Interval@#[[1]], Interval@#[[2]]] &, 
  minsAndMaxes, {1}];
displayPoints = RandomReal[{Min[#], Max[#]}] & /@ groupIntersections;

(*Show issue with Epilog and BarSpacing in Manipulate*)
Manipulate[BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
  ChartLabels -> {{"2002", "2001", "2000"}, None}, 
  BarSpacing -> {within, between},
  Epilog -> {Green, Opacity[.6], PointSize[.02], 
    MapIndexed[
     Tooltip[Point[{First@#2 2 - .5, #1}], NumberForm[#1, {2, 1}]] &, 
      displayPoints]}], 
 {{within, Tiny}, {Tiny, Medium, Large}}, 
 {{between, Medium}, {Tiny, Medium, Large}}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure how you want to place the `displaypoints` relative to the boxes, but ... you can find the coordinates of the bounding boxes using the `ChartElementFunction` as follows:

```
Manipulate[Module[{boundingboxes = {}}, 
  Row[{BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartStyle -> {Red, Purple}, ImageSize -> 400,
     BarOrigin -> barorigin, BarSpacing -> {within, between},
     ChartElementFunction -> ({Opacity[.3], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
         boundingboxes = Append[boundingboxes, #1]; 
         Rectangle @@ Transpose[#1], Opacity[1], 
         ChartElementDataFunction["GlassBoxWhisker"][##]} &), 
     Method -> {"BoxWidth" -> boxwidth}, 
     ChartLabels -> {{"2002", "2001", "2000"}, None}], 
    Panel[Grid[boundingboxes], "bounding boxes", Top]}, Spacer[10]]], 
   {{within, Tiny}, {Tiny, Medium, Large}}, 
   {{between, Medium}, {Tiny, Medium, Large}}, 
   {{boxwidth, "Scaled"}, {"Scaled", "Fixed"}},
   {{barorigin, Bottom}, {Bottom, Top, Left, Right}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Reap/Sow` combination:

```
Reap[BoxWhiskerChart[data, BarSpacing->{Tiny, Large}, Method->{"BoxWidth" -> "Scaled"},
   ChartElementFunction->((Sow[#1]; ChartElementDataFunction["GlassBoxWhisker"][##])&),
   ChartLabels -> {{"2002", "2001", "2000"}, None}]][[2,1]]
```

> {{{0.045229, 0.949808}, {-3.38525, 4.19586}}, 
>           {{1.04027,  1.94485}, {-2.68183, 3.84264}}, 
>           {{2.98985, 3.89443}, {-3.25875,  4.67004}}, 
>           {{3.98489, 4.88947}, {-2.16572, 4.60291}}, 
>           {{5.93447, 6.83905}, {-4.05161, 4.48291}}, 
>           {{6.92951, 7.83409}, {-2.78972, 5.82866}}}

**Update:** Using the bounding box coordinates in `Epilog`:

```
Table[Labeled[Module[{boundingboxes = {}, xcoords = {}}, 
    bwc = BoxWhiskerChart[data, ChartStyle -> {Red, Purple}, 
      ImageSize -> 300, BarSpacing -> {within, between}, 
      ChartElementFunction -> ((boundingboxes = 
       Append[boundingboxes, #1]; ChartElementDataFunction["GlassBoxWhisker"][##]) &)];
    xcoords = Mean[{#[[1, -1]], #[[2, 1]]}] & /@ 
      Partition[boundingboxes[[All, 1]], 2]; 
    Show[bwc, Epilog -> {Green, Opacity[.6], PointSize[.02], 
       Tooltip[Point[#], NumberForm[#[[2]], {2, 1}]] & /@ 
        Transpose[{xcoords, displayPoints}]}]], 
   Row[{"{within, between} = {", within, ", ", between, "}"}], Top], 
   {within, {Tiny, Medium, Large}}, 
   {between, {Tiny, Medium, Large}}] // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

**Note:** For `BarOrigin->Left` and `BarOrigin->Right` we need to change `Partition[boundingboxes[[All, 1]], 2]` to `Partition[boundingboxes[[All, 2]], 2]` and `Transpose[{xcoords, displayPoints}]` to `Reverse/@Transpose[{xcoords, displayPoints}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the chart element functions.  However, it appears that I can't use `boundingboxes` in the `Epilog` option to place my points at mid-way between the box plot regions as it shows as empty `{}` when referenced.  Is there a way to get `Epilog` to see the filled `boundingboxes`?  I used the following: `Epilog -> {Green, Opacity[.6], PointSize[.02],
  MapIndexed[Tooltip[
     Point[
      {Mean[{boundingboxes[[First@#2 2 - 1, 1, 2]] , 
         boundingboxes[[First@#2 2, 1, 1]]}], #1}],
     NumberForm[#1, {2, 1}]] &, displayPoints]}`

Comment: Edmund, please see the update.

Comment: Wow! Very, very nice.  Thanks!

Comment: @Edmund, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.