# How do I overlay things onto a BarChart?

Tags: graphics, charts

I have a fairly complex sort of `BarChart` that I want to overlay with other graphics. For concreteness, let's assume that I want to overlay a `LinePlot`. In doing so, I found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21126/531) quite helpful, but my chart has some additional wrinkles which complicate things. First, let's invent some data:

```
data = {Association["a" -> 0.7037417451289036, 
    "b" -> 0.503687396357559, "c" -> 0.8305301936239331, 
    "d" -> 0.23466296631845518], Association[
    "a" -> 0.08369185073518004, "b" -> 0.5808357340946317, 
    "c" -> 1.873919922991976, "d" -> 1.3981710526525974], 
   Association["a" -> 1.6327509774236528, "b" -> 1.3925276568460028, 
    "c" -> 1.1036001759467897, "d" -> 1.0264775292307071], 
   Association["a" -> 3.218464871800018, "b" -> 0.6400499501591295, 
    "c" -> 0.4775621030459698, "d" -> 2.375619997842695], 
   Association["a" -> 3.160797696474269, "b" -> 0.36822672048523586, 
    "c" -> 3.862723785325967, "d" -> 0.41766552167593396]};
```

Then I'll whip up a `BarChart`:

```
bars = BarChart[data, ChartLegends -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

[image: so a duck walks into a bar...]

Now for the `ListPlot`, using the [`DataRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataRange.html) trick suggested by that [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21126/531).

```
means = Mean /@ data;

lines = ListPlot[means, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  DataRange -> {2.5, 2.5 + 4*4}]
```

[image]

Now I can `Show` the two together:

```
Show[bars, lines, ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}]
```

[image]

As you can see, it's almost, but not quite, right. Evidently the spacing between the groups throws things off, but I'm not entirely sure how much, in part because I'm not sure how much spacing there *is* between bars. It's complicated by the fact that there are two different sorts of spacing, one within groups of bars, and one between bars, and the two seem to affect the $x$-coördinates of the bars in different ways. I could set [`BarSpacings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarSpacing.html) to `{None, None}`, but that looks ugly.

Is there a better way? Or a simple way of understanding how bars are spaced when they're divided into groups?

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77784

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this:

Get the tick values:

```
ticks = FrameTicks /. Options[First @ bars, FrameTicks]
```

Get the x tick values:

```
 xticks = ticks[[2, 1, All, 1]]
```

Visualize the x tick values with dots on top of the bar chart:

```
Show[bars, Graphics[{AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[{#, 0}]} & /@ xticks]]
```

[image]

This gives you all the center points of each bar, but also the center points between the groups of bars. Get rid of those:

```
xticks2 = Drop[xticks, {5, -1, 5}]
```

Using those x ticks values, use the first and last of each group to find the center x coordinate of each group:

```
line = Table[
 Line[{
  {(xticks2[[4 i]] + xticks2[[4 i - 3]])/2, means[[i]]}, 
  {(xticks2[[4 (1 + i)]] + xticks2[[1 + 4 i]])/2, means[[i + 1]]}}
 ], 
{i, 1, 4}]
```

Make the new plot, with the line points centered on the bar groups:

```
Show[bars, Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[5], line}]]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, since it's pretty clever. Still, it fails if `FrameTicks` has been replaced with a custom value, which is a possibility.

Comment: You can probably make this work with any custom FrameTicks, but I haven't tried that case.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe here's a small improvement

```
Show[
 bars,
 ListLinePlot[means, DataRange -> {2.6, 19}],
 ListPlot[means, DataRange -> {2.6, 19}],
 GridLines -> {{2.6, 6.7, 10.8, 14.9, 19}, {1, 2, 3, 4}},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}}]
```

[image]

The gridlines run through the centers of the "meshpoints" and are uniformely spaced at

```
{2.6, 6.7, 10.8, 14.9, 19.0} // Differences
```

> {4.1, 4.1, 4.1, 4.1}

Comment: how did you find the gridlines' XX coordinates? (trying to adapt this to my problem)

Comment: By trial and error - but didn't take too long

Comment: :P I now remembered there's the "Get coordinates" thing where you can see them quickly!

Answer (score 2):

Use the option `Joined -> Automatic`

```
bars = BarChart[data, ChartLegends -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, All}, Joined -> Automatic]
```

and post-process the `Line`s to get the mean of each group:

```
ppF = # /. Line[x_] /; FreeQ[x, _Offset] :> Point[Mean[x]] /. 
 pts : {___, ({dirs__, _Point} ..)} :> {Thickness[.01], 
   CapForm["Round"], PointSize[Large], 
   Through[{Point, Line}[(pts /. {} -> Sequence[])[[All, -1, 1]]]]}&;

ppF @ bars
```

[image]

Using a different option value for `BarSpacing`:

```
bars2 = BarChart[data, ChartLegends -> {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, All}, BarSpacing->{Large, Large}, Joined -> Automatic]

ppF @ bars2
```

[image]