# How do I determine which ChartElementDataFunction is Automatic?

Tags: implementation-details, charts

In the course of exploring [@kglr's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77812/531) to [Edmund's question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77784/531) gain some insight into how I might answer [my own question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98817/how-do-i-overlay-things-onto-a-barchart), I came across the undocumented `` System`ChartElementData `` function, which evidently allows you to map the strings passed as options to `ChartElementFunction` to the actual functions which draw the elements. Thus, using the calling convention described for `BoxChart` in the [docs for `ChartElementFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElementFunction.html), you can do the following:

```
In[1]:= cfd = ChartElementData["Rectangle"]
Out[1]= ChartElementDataFunction["Rectangle"]

In[2]:= cfd[{{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 1, "foo"]
Out[2]= Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, "RoundingRadius" -> 0]
```

That's pretty neat. However, you can also find out that there are many applicable, named, `ChartElementDataFunctions` for any given chart type:

```
In[3]:= ChartElementData["BarChart"]
Out[3]= {"ArrowRectangle", "EdgeFadingRectangle", "FadingRectangle", 
         "GlassRectangle", "GradientRectangle", "GradientScaleRectangle", 
         "ObliqueRectangle", "Rectangle", "SegmentScaleRectangle"}
```

Looking at some output, I'm pretty sure that `"Rectangle"` is the default for `BarChart`, but I'm not 100% certain, and it would be nice to avoid having to do trial and error for every bar type should I wish to discover the default. Is there a way to find, programmatically, what `ChartElementDataFunction` is used by any given chart type when it's passed `ChartElementFunction -> Automatic`?

Comment: `TracePrint[(* charting function *), ChartElementDataFunction[_], TraceInternal -> True]` quickly reveals not a few secrets.

Comment: @J.M., if you don't write that up as an answer, how am I supposed to give you your bounty? :)

Comment: It doesn't always work, you see: `TracePrint[PieChart3D[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"], ChartElementDataFunction[_], TraceInternal -> True]` so I left it as a comment.

Comment: @J.M. Got it. Still a good start, though.

Comment: For `"Marketing"`, this works: ``ChartElementFunction /. Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Marketing", BarChart3D]``. For some of the other plot themes this doesn't work, but the previously presented approach works. I don't know if there's a situation where neither will work, but this at least reveals some inconsistency in internal handling.

Answer (score 4):

Some `ChartElementDataFunction`s have options and some plot themes (namely, `"Business"`, `"Marketing"` and  `"Monochrome"`) use these options. So, the pattern we need to use in the second argument of `Trace` is `ChartElementDataFunction[__]`. With this small change we can use J.M.'s suggested approach to discover the default `ChartElementFunction` for every pairing of charting functions and plot themes.

```
ClearAll[traceCEF]
traceCEF[th_] := Last[Flatten @
  Trace[#[If[# === PairedBarChart, ## & @@ #2, #2], PlotTheme -> th], 
        ChartElementDataFunction[__], TraceInternal -> True]] /. 
     HoldPattern[ChartElementDataFunction[b__][__] | 
        ChartElementDataFunction[b__]] :> Column[{b}] &;

themes = {Automatic, "Business", "Marketing", "Monochrome"};

charts = {BarChart, BarChart3D, BoxWhiskerChart, BubbleChart, 
   BubbleChart3D, DistributionChart, GeoBubbleChart, PairedBarChart, 
   PieChart, PieChart3D, RectangleChart, RectangleChart3D, 
   SectorChart, SectorChart3D};

simpleinput = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, 
   Partition[Range@6, 3], Partition[Range@8, 4], {1, 2, 3}, 
   {GeoPosition[{1, 1}] -> 1, GeoPosition[{2, 2}] -> 2}, 
   Partition[Range@6, 3], {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, Partition[Range@6, 2],
   Partition[Range@6, 3], Partition[Range@6, 2], Partition[Range@6, 3]};

grid = Join[{Join[Item[Style[#, 14], Background -> LightBlue] & /@ {"function", 
       "PlotTheme"}, {SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft, SpanFromLeft}]}, 
    {Prepend[Item[Style[#, 14], Background -> LightBlue] & /@ themes, SpanFromAbove]}, 
   MapThread[Prepend[Table[traceCEF[t][##], {t, themes}], 
      Item[Style[#, 14], Background -> LightBlue]] &, 
     {charts, simpleinput}]];

Grid[grid, Dividers -> {{True, True, {False}, True}, All}, 
 Alignment -> {Left, Center, {{1, 2} -> Center}}]
```

[image]

The other themes

```
themes = Prepend[Complement["Base" /. Charting`$PlotThemes, 
   {"Business", "Marketing",  "Monochrome"}], Automatic]
```

> ```
>  {Automatic, "Classic", "Detailed", "Minimal", "Scientific", "Web"}
> ```

use the same `ChartElementFunction` for each charting function:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! $\phantom{}$

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`AbsoluteOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html) is for, but it actually doesn't work for me (v11.2), even though the doc states:

> gives the absolute settings of options specified in an expression such as a graphics object.

Your question *should* be answered by:

```
AbsoluteOptions[
    BarChart[...],
    ChartElementFunction
 ]
```