# Displaying horizontal axis as legend of a chart/plot?

Tags: plotting, labeling, alignment, charts

I'm trying to do a `BarChart[]` of some data and I'd like to add an additional XX axis *below* the chart with some additional information. This may also be done with an additional plot, as long as it does the job.

So my question is: how can I align the second plot to *the XX axis*, not to the plot itself?

In the example below I want from `a` to the end of `g`to include the labeling "first", from `h` to `k` to have "second", etc.

```
data = Transpose@{CharacterRange["a", "t"], 
    Table[RandomInteger[{1, 20}], {20}]};
padding = {{7, 7}, {10, 7}};
plot1 = BarChart[
   data[[All, 2]],
   ChartLabels -> data[[All, 1]]
   ];
plot2 = Plot["", {x, 1, 20}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   Ticks -> {{{0, ""}, {3.5, "first", {0, 0}}, {7, ""}, {8.5, 
       "second", {0, 0}}, {10, ""}, {13, "third", {0, 0}}, {16, 
       ""}, {18, "fourth", {0, 0}}, {20, ""}}, None}
   ];
GraphicsColumn[{plot1, plot2}]
(*out:*)
```

[image]

I have found some other questions and answers regarding plot/graphic alignment, but none regarding the alignment to the axis itself. I'd appreciate all help!

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98817

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[{1, 20}], {20}];
```

Define the partition

```
par = {{1, 8}, {9, 13}, {14, 16}, {17, 20}};
```

Plot

```
BarChart[
 Take[data, #] & /@ par,
   ChartLabels -> {{"1st", "2d", "3rd", "4th"}, CharacterRange["a", "t"]}]
```

[image]

**Update**

```
bar =
 BarChart[
  data,
  ChartLabels -> CharacterRange["a", "t"]];

lip =
 ListPlot[
  ConstantArray[20, 20],
  AxesOrigin -> {1, -3},
  Frame -> True,
  FrameStyle -> {{Black, Opacity@0}, {Black, Opacity@0}},
  FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, 20, 5], None}, {{{1, "a"}, {4, "first", 0}, {7, "g"}, {9.5, "2nd", 0}, {12, "l"}, {14, "n"}, {20, "t"}}, None}},
  PlotStyle -> Opacity@0]
```

[image]

```
Show[{lip, bar}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I had also thought about that. However, I'd prefer to really have a bar under as it would give more emphasis to the bar. I may also want to change the bar itself to add some more information, so I'd like to avoid having the labels presented like that

Answer (score 2):

For a quick and dirty method you could make use of `RectangleChart` as your second where the width of each rectangle is equal to the number of items in the top groups.  Grouping your data in the `BarChart` will assist with visualising this.

```
bc = BarChart[Partition[data[[All, 2]], 5],
  ChartLabels -> {IntegerName[Range[4]], CharacterRange["a", "t"]}];
rc = RectangleChart[{{4, 5}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 6}}, 
  ChartLabels -> IntegerName[Range[4]]];
GraphicsColumn[{bc, rc}]
```

[image]

You will have to tweak the `PlotRangePadding` to get them to line up just so. You can use the `ColorFunction` option to keep the colour the same on each bar.

There is a better way were you can grab the bounds of the rectangles of the bars in the `BarChart` and use them in the `RectangleChart` for the width of the rectangles. See this post for details on how to use the `ChartElementFunction` option to get these. [What are Epilog x-Axis Positions In BoxWhiskerChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77784)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about your answer and @eldo's above, there may be a way to combine them more easily. Maybe duplicate the top plot, use the labeling such that only the groups ("first", "second"...) and not the bars ("a", "b"...) are labeled and then group them as you are suggesting with the padding. This has the advantage of yielding more approximate sizes than creating another chart altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Another way, using Frame (you need to shift your endpoints by 0.5 to match the bars)

```
data = Transpose@{CharacterRange["a", "t"], 
    Table[RandomInteger[{1, 20}], {20}]};
plot1 = BarChart[data[[All, 2]], ChartLabels -> data[[All, 1]]];
plot2 = Plot["", {x, 1, 20}, Frame -> {{False, False}, {True, False}},
   Axes -> False, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{0.5, ""}, {4, "first", {0, 0}}, {7.5, ""}, {9, 
       "second", {0, 0}}, {10.5, ""}, {13.5, "third", {0, 0}}, {16.5, 
       ""}, {18.5, "fourth", {0, 0}}, {20.5, ""}}, None}];
Show[plot2, plot1, PlotRange -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 2]
```

[image]